Receiving error of vulnerabilities when trying to install figlet, how to fix them?
nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via npm audit fix --force
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/nth-check
css-select  <=3.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-select
svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/svgo
@svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
@svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@svgr/webpack
react-scripts  >=2.1.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
node_modules/react-scripts
I tried npm audit fix --force but still giving an issue
